# Locating a table data row data without iterating

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can we locate a table row data with a simple expression like this instead of iterating through the entire table items. I am using this simple expression

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr//td[contains(text(),\"Row 1, Column 1\")])"));
```

for this site

```
String URL="http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_tables.htm";
driver.navigate().to(URL);
```

but i am getting this error
The xpath expression '//table//tr//td[contains(text(),"Row 1, Column 1")])' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

I know the usual realative path and ablsolute path expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it maybe your syntax causing the problem try:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr//td[contains(text(),'Row 1, Column 1')]"));
```

Comment: This xpath finds two matches on the page. I recommend using chrome with the XPath Helper app to help create useful xpaths.

Answer (score 1):

To locate a table row based on it containing a cell with specific text you can use the following XPath locator:

```
 //tr[td[text()='myCellText']]
```

Comment: You can also use the contains function if only a portion of the text in a cell is known:

`//tr[td[contains(text(),'partialText')]]`